# Lightning App Builder: how to check if an app is active?

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, tooling-api

I have created an app via `Lightning App Builder` called `testApp` how can you verify if the app is activated using Rest API/SOQL/APEX?

I have tried using [FlexiPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flexipage.htm?search_text=flexi) but it does not support field that shows the status.

Is there any other way to check Lightning App Builder with the API?

Comment: I don't think there's an `active` flag for apps, only `visible`. Apps are "always active", but not visible for everyone by default.